# problem with removing Totals in RpivotTable

Tags: r, shiny, pivot-table, dashboard, rpivottable

Can someone please help me in removing Totals coming up in RpivotTable as shown in the diagram. I'm adding the code as well.
Stuck on its since long, please guide.

Regards

```
library(rpivotTable)
rpivotTable(data = mtcars, subtotals = FALSE, rows = c( "cyl"),cols=c("carb"), vals = "mpg", aggregatorName = "Sum", rendererName = "Table", width="50%", height="550px")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of rPivottable doesn’t allow you to remove totals, but the next version likely will.

Comment: Thanks nicolas, can you pls let me know when will the next version be available?

Comment: i want to ask you one more thing, the url of shiny app doesn't load, in log it says out of memory, i don't want to minimize my dataset, can you please suggest me a solution?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, i have 2 questions. 1) Can i hide totals if not delete? 2) Can i increase the width of drop downs? as some strings are big and unreadable in drop down unless scrolled to left

Answer (score 2):

Subtotals can be removed presented on the 6th row below:

```
library(pivottabler)

pt <- PivotTable$new()

pt$addData(data)

pt$addColumnDataGroups("Date")  

pt$addRowDataGroups("SKU.ID" ,  addTotal=FALSE) 

pt$addRowDataGroups("Location" ,  addTotal=FALSE)

pt$renderPivot()

pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="Total Sales Qty", summariseExpression="sum(Sales_Qty, na.rm=TRUE)")

pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="TotalSalesQty")
pt$renderPivot()
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working like this through CSS (a workaround since only the display is hidden):

```
mypivottable <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(mypivottable,
     htmltools::tags$style(
     ".pvtTotalLabel, .colTotal, .rowTotal, .pvtGrandTotal { display: none; }"
     )
  )
```

I dont think it works in Shiny app though.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from [szapiszapo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8057984/szapiszapo) works for Shiny apps if you add
`tags$style( ".pvtTotalLabel, .colTotal, .rowTotal, .pvtGrandTotal { display: none; }" )`
to the UI. e.g.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$style(
        ".pvtTotalLabel, .colTotal, .rowTotal, .pvtGrandTotal { display: none; }"
    ),
    rpivotTableOutput("pivot_table", height = "100%")
)
```